# MAAS Internal Server Error after update

Tags: server, updates, juju, maas, openstack

I'm trying to deploy OpenStack Havana over Ubuntu Precise using juju.

This is what I do exactly:

- Install Ubuntu server with maas following the official guide.
- sudo maas createsuperuser
- sudo apt-get install maas-dhcp maas-dns
- sudo ufw disable
- sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
- sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:havana
- sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install juju-core
- sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
- sudo maas-import-pxe-file

At this point everything seems O.K. till I reboot the server.
when I browse MAAS URL I get Internal Server Error "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.50.240 Port 80"

This is the last errors at apache2 log

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6877380/

I tried this for three times and I got the same error.
Any clue what I did wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I repeated the same practice without "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" and the error was gone.